# How does one sync storyboards, orientation, launch-images and view background images

Tags: ios, storyboard

My purpose is that the initial view will have the same background image as the launchimage.

I am provided a way to define my portrait and landscape launch images.

however, the initial view, if I'm using storyboard is portrait. If I set an imageView on top of it for the background image, it will be shown wrong if I start in landscape.

where am I given the chance in storyboard to split up between landscape and portrait so that I can have two different images for both possible modes **for the same view**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options :-

1) if ios 6 you can use autolayout . 2) you can set frames for the uicontrols separately and use these two methods if ios 6

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ;//return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and after this whereever required like in ViewDidlOAd() and viewWillAppear() do this

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication ]statusBarOrientation))
{
// change frames
}
else
{
// for landscape change frames here
}
```

iOS < 6.x

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation // Deprecated in iOS 6.x 
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the view will appear method of your initial view, check the interface orientation and replace the background view accordingly with whatever image you need to display.

You can do this as well in for different screen sizes (iphone 4 - 5)

Answer (score 0):

if you allow both landscape and portrait startup, then you must prepare two UIImageView.

You can disable the landscape orientation while startup in project properties. Choose the build target, and uncheck Landscape Left/Right in Deployment Info section.